# Drop Down to Set Initialize Value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to set the default values on all fields using drop down. **For example:**
`Let consider Drop down there is of three options like theme1, theme2 and theme`3 and I have `5 input fields.` In the `five input fields` have appropriate `id`.

If i select the `theme1` it initialize the value to the appropriate `5` input field.(I am not sure is there is a way to assign the values to the array)

Theme1 contatin

```
input1 => "hi";
input2 => "how";
input3 =>"are";
input4 =>"you";
```

If i select the theme1 in drop down then add the values as i defined in array(If it is feasible)
  Theme2
 contatin

```
input1 => "glad";
input2 => "to";
input3 =>"meet";
input4 =>"you";
```

If i select the `theme2` it initialize the value to the appropriate `5` input field.(This value is differ with theme1)

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            $('#price').val('$' + $(this).attr('value'));
    });

});
```

Right now i mentioned with value. But is there is a way to call the function instead of 
Can anyone Propose me to do this with set of initialize value to the one option(theme1) using array.
Here is my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chnUn/107/)**

Comment: you want to initialize the selected value to each input box??

Comment: @SarathSprakash For each selection has contain array of value to assign in input field if the selection is 1 then add the custom values for five field already declared in array is it possible

Comment: lets say I select the theme1 in the select , Then the corresponding value to be appeard on the 5 input boxes, is that it?

Comment: Yes i edited my ques. What you are saying is correct and exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: Kindly check now the below fiddle ...http://jsfiddle.net/chnUn/112/  . Is that is what you want ?

Comment: I think you wanted something like this ..http://jsfiddle.net/chnUn/113/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/j7SR6/)**

Try this

### code

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var data = $(this).val().split(' ');
    var i = 0;
    $('input').each(function () {

        $(this).val(data[i]);
        i++;

    });
});
```

### html

```
<select>
    <option>Select an item</option>
    <option value="Hello how are you">Item 1</option>
    <option value="Glad to meet you">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="price">
<input type="text" id="another_price">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. http://jsfiddle.net/JGp9e/277/ I tried this one it also works great.